# Web API 2 does not say unauthorized when HTTP method not supported

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, authorization, bearer-token

I was just testing a new POST method, and I accidentally sent an unauthorized GET request, and the response I got was:

```
"message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."
```

But when I sent a POST request, I got this response:

```
"message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
```

Shouldn't I be getting the unauthorized message no matter what I do if I'm not authorized or even authenticated?

Here's the method:

```
[Route("api/search"), HttpPost, Authorize]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Search()
{
   ...
}
```

I have tried decorating the controller, and the method with the `[Authorize]` attribute, and I have a global filter set as well.

Answer (score 1):

The message you got back for `GET` was entirely accurate. You don't have a GET decorated action, so therefore `The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'`.

Your concern about getting the not authorized instead doesn't work due to the fact that the API must first try and find a method that matches your request signature. Since it can't find a `GET` then it returns the error for that.

Comment: So it's by design, which is expected I guess. I'm surprised though, since I imagine it should be possible for WebAPI to already know whether I'm authorized before doing anything else, I expected to always get unauthorized errors no matter what so no information leaks out of the API to be used maliciously.

Comment: Routing happens first apparently. I don't have documentation to back it up, but based on behavior it seems to be the case.